# is parallel write to eventfd is safe?

Tags: linux, kernel, file-descriptors

I have a multi threaded environment so parallel write to `eventfd` is possible. Is parallel write to `eventfd` is safe? Is there any official doc that explains this behavior of `eventfd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the kernel sources (here 5.4.48), you can find the implementation of the functions that handle reads from/writes to eventfd file descriptors:

```c
// fs/eventfd.c

static ssize_t eventfd_read(struct file *file, char __user *buf, size_t count,
                            loff_t *ppos)
{
        struct eventfd_ctx *ctx = file->private_data;
        ...
        spin_lock_irq(&ctx->wqh.lock);

static ssize_t eventfd_write(struct file *file, const char __user *buf, size_t count,
                             loff_t *ppos)
{
        struct eventfd_ctx *ctx = file->private_data;
        ...
        spin_lock_irq(&ctx->wqh.lock);
```

The implementation has internal locking, which will make it thread safe.